# Edit item in list<className> with linq

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I have a generic list.

It is full.

its name is list1.

We want to use LINQ, to edit its Items.

intput ------> textbox1.text (Key in the list1)

key in class11--------> string _number

What is the code Edit?

**Update**

Here is what i want:

```
List lst= new List();

lst.Add("Shekhar1");

lst.Add("Shekhar2");

lst.Add("Shekhar3");

lst.Add("Shekhar4");

lst.Add("Shekhar5");

//code edit item (Shekhar3) -------> Shekhar88 //code to edit the item...?????
```

Output:

```
Shekhar1

Shekhar2

Shekhar88

Shekhar4

Shekhar5
```

for edit (update) the item in generic list:

1- Search with linq to generic list -------> output index item

2- lst.RemoveAt(index)

3- lst.Insert(index, new obj);

ok....!!?
please give me code linq. (case 1)

thanx

Comment: Please correct your question a little i can't Decipher the question here.

Comment: i want edit the item in the list<T> with use linq

Comment: ok i have given an answer.. is that what you want..

Comment: Why using LINQ? `lst[lst.IndexOf("Shekhar3")] = "Shekhar88";`. Mind that you need to check if item exist.

Comment: May write a perfect example. thanx

Answer (score 4):

Well i dont know what you want here but what i think is you want to edit the item in List by using LINQ with some other data may be in a text box.

Anyway Here is an Example to give you an Idea on how o get started: (Run on LINQPAD)

```
List<string> lst= new List<string>();

lst.Add("Shekhar");
lst.Add("Shekhar");
lst.Add("Shekhar");
lst.Add("Shekhar");
lst.Add("Shekhar");

var edited = (from item in lst  
            select (item = "Pro")).ToList();
lst = edited;

lst.Dump();
```

Output:

```
Pro

Pro

Pro
Pro
Pro
```

**Update**

Ok based on your suggestions here is the code that will work

```
string search_string = "Shekhar3";
string replacement_string = "Shekhar88";
lst = (lst.Select( item => {
                          if(item == search_string) return item = replacement_string;
                          else return item;
                              })).ToList();
```

Comment: Can be shorten to: `lst.Select(item => item = "Pro
");`

Comment: +1 Yeah i know.. just didn't did that... thanx for suggestion

Comment: @HuBeZa with your code we still need to convert to List as the query make it an IEnumerable List.. as i have show in my update

Comment: please answer with down case. thanx

Comment: oh ok an upddate in answer.. you should have updated that in your question itself...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mean that you want to edit an item in the list, based on what the user types in? IE: Filter the list of objects based on some predicate?

If this is the case, you could do it with linq like so:

```
List<MyType> myList = PopulateList();

string key = textBox1.Text;
string newValue = "new value";

// If you only want a single item...
MyType item = (from item in myList
              where item.Key == key
              select key).FirstOrDefault();

// If you want a list of matching items
List<MyType> items = from item in myList
                     where item.Key == key
                     select key;
```

You can then edit the items you want either directly:

```
item.Value = newValue;
```

Or by iterating:

```
foreach(MyType i in items)
{
    i.Value = newValue;
}
```

You can achieve the same without LINQ by simply calling the .Where() function with a lambda expression, for example:

```
List<MyType> items = myList.Where(i => i.Key == key);
```

Comment: I should I use this method. list1.Remove(item) And list1.Insert(index); index is int.

Comment: @mah_85: Depends on what you are actually doing. If it's just removing and adding a string from a small list, either is just as good. If you have very large lists, or lists of more complex objects then updating in place is certainly easier and potentially quicker too.

Comment: please answer with down case. thanx

Comment: output in it cod not index item

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to select into a new list, but not modify an existing list.  The reason is that Linq deals with enumerables and not lists internally.  The same code that works with lists could work with arrays or with a function that returns an enumerable and `yield`s values.  Here's how to replace an item using `Select()` [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/ylsraF):

```
List<string> list = (new string[] { 
    "Shekhar1", "Shekhar2", "Shekhar3", "Shekhar4", "Shekhar5" }
).ToList();

string match = "Shekhar3";
string replace = "Shekhar88";
List<string> newList = list.Select(x => x == match ? replace : x).ToList();
list = newList;
foreach (string value in list) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", value);
}
```